# bash if statement doesn't work as expected

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm new in bash scripting.

I use this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
ende="100"
while true; do
  out=$(php '/var/www/testsh.php' $count)
  if [ "$out"!=="$ende" ] 
  then
    echo "$out i break"
    break
  fi
  echo "sleeping"
  sleep 10
  ((count++))
done
```

In my PHP: echo '100';

./test.sh gives me:
100 i break

but it should output sleeping till `$out` is not 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"$out"!=="$ende"` gets substituted into `100!==100`, which is a non-empty string, which `[` evaluate the same as `-n 100!==100` - true, because it is a non-zero string.

`"$out" != "$ende"` would get substituted into `100 != 100` which is an operator with two operands, and evaluates to false (as it compares two strings).

In a different scenario, `!=` might produce a *logical* error, since it compares operands as strings. Fortunately, equality of strings in your case is identical to equality of integers (for which you would use `-ne`), but don't count for it always to be the case.

- In `[`, operators need their space
- In `[`, there's no such thing as `!==`
- For integers, use `-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt`, `-ge`

Also, you might like `seq`:

```
for count in $(seq 100)
do
  # will happen 100 times, with `count` from `0` to `99`
done
```

Comment: Might be better to suggest a C-style loop than a `seq` :)

Comment: @mickp `seq` is shelly and seqsy. :)